# Why do I catch "Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential)."?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm writing a neural network that makes a prediction based on a 700*700 image. I train a model on a sample (146, 700, 700, 1). When I try to get a neural network forecast for one of the elements of this sample, this is what I get:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 700, 700, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 700, 700, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 700, 1, 1).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: in user code:

    ...

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 980000, but received input with shape (None, 5600)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 700, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Before trying to get the forecast, I checked the dimensionality of the data again and did not find any error. Here's the code for creating the model, training it, and trying to get a prediction:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(700, 700, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same'),
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1,  activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])


imgs = imgs.reshape(train_size, 700, 700, 1)


model.fit(imgs, labels, epochs=1, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=1)
print(model.predict(imgs[0]), labels[0])
```

I can't find a description of a similar error on SOF or other forums

I tried to find my error in the data dimensions, but I couldn’t find it.